# images not visible on iPad : cover css attribute?

Tags: jquery, css, ipad

In my webapp a button is added to the screen when a map div opens using css:

```
 background: url("../img/btn-map-fullscreen.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;   / cover transparent;
```

I am not familiar with the ' / cover transparent ' syntax (someone else wrote this part)...

...but as it is, the button appears as expected in Chrome, FF, even IE...but the button is not visible on an iPad.  The functionality is still there; the button exists but is not visible.

If I remove only ' / cover transparent ' ...then the buttons are visible on the iPad (and on my desktop browsers) but are choppy lookig, and not correctly.

I've tried some combinations but I haven't yet figured out how to make these buttons visible the same way on an iPad as they are on my desktop..ideas?

I am using JQuery btw ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is using the [CSS 3 background shorthand](http://dev.opera.com/static/dstorey/backgrounds/background-shorthand.html) and `cover` is a value for the [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-size) property. The shorthand also includes the `background-origin` and `background-clip` properties. However, I don't think its supported in iOS as of yet, so you should instead try to separate it:

```
.class {
background-image: url("../img/btn-map-fullscreen.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-size: cover;
background-color: transparent;
}
```